# Android interrupt media player with ringtone manager

Tags: android, ringtonemanager

I have used ringtonemanager previously in android studio and it seemed to lower the volume of any music that was playing in a different app to play the alert i was trying to play, then once my alert had completed the background music would then come back to normal volume (as the default alarm/notification would do) But now a year or so later im trying to implement this again but my alert cannot be heard over the music playing in Google Play Music.

Is this a change that now requires additional parameters to function as it used to?

Im using:

```
Uri notification = 
RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
myRM = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this.getContext(), notification);
myRM.play();
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Handling Changes in Audio Output](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones.html#audio-focus) seems what fits your need.

In short, you need to request audio focus before starting playing.

```
...
mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(null, mStreamType, AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK);
mRingtone.play();
```

> AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK
>
> Used to indicate a temporary request of audio focus, anticipated to
>   last a short amount of time, and where it is acceptable for other
>   audio applications to keep playing after having lowered their output
>   level (also referred to as "ducking").

Remember to release audio focus when finishing..

```
if (mRingtone != null && mRingtone.isPlaying()) {
    mRingtone.stop();
}
mRingtone = null;
if (mAudioManager != null) {
    mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much